# How can i get "Click" event work with my WPF button when I use EventTrigger from the Expression Blend Interactivity assembly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, command

I'm attempting to use a Command, defined in my view model with EventTriggers as defined in xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

I have changed the control from a Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.SurfaceSlider-derived control to a regular WPF Button. With the Button, the same ConfirmOrderCommand gets fired if I use the EventName="MouseEnter", but if I use EventName="Click" nothing happens. The XAML for the Button is here.

```
<Button Name="ConfirmButton"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
          Style="{StaticResource  ConfirmButtonStyle}"
          >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ConfirmOrderCommand}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </Button>
```

I want the user to be able to click the button to fire the command. Can I get the Click event to work for a Button, or do I need to look for another event? I've also failed to get MouseLeftButtonUp to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual reason the Button.Click would not work, was determined after much pain and finally asking someone on the project after he woke up in the morning.

Our application was stealing almost all of the Button events with FrameworkElement Preview delegates.

```
public static void RegisterEvents(FrameworkElement parent)
{
    parent.PreviewMouseDown += MouseDown;
    parent.PreviewMouseUp += MouseUp;
    // even more of these
}
```

The delegates would then use System.Window.Input.TouchDevice to ReportDown() in the case of MouseDown etc. All this time I just thought I didn't know how the standard WPF button usually works. I guess the moral of this story is events don't have to start at the child control and then propagate up to their containers until Handled = true. Preview allows the container to capture the events first.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I have the same problem. I didn't get where I should put code snippet you explained above. Could you give me more detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try EventName="Button.Click". Anyways, you can just set the Command Property of the Button itself, and remove the Interaction.Triggers part.

Comment: I could do this with Mouse.Enter, but not Button.Click. My answer describes why this was the case.